# How to set columns based on selected tab in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables, tabulator

I have few tabs in which each of tab is having data table.
I'm trying to use tabulator and based on active tab I'm trying to set columns.

I used `setColumns` method but I'm getting an error: 
`Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Please find `jsfiddle` link with my code in it:

```
  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    layout: "fitColumns",
    //data : tabledata,
    autoColumns: true,

  });
  if (this.activeTabName == "Role Card") {
    let columns: [{
        title: "Name",
        field: "name",
        sorter: "string",
        width: 200
      },
      {
        title: "Progress",
        field: "progress",
        sorter: "number",
        formatter: "progress"
      },
      {
        title: "Gender",
        field: "gender",
        sorter: "string"
      },
      {
        title: "Rating",
        field: "rating",
        formatter: "star",
        align: "center",
        width: 100
      },
      {
        title: "Favourite Color",
        field: "col",
        sorter: "string"
      },
    ]
    table.setColumns(columns)
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qc9r8t4p/

Please help me out in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code that is resulting in the ***columns*** variable being undefined when you pass it into the setColumns function

where you assign the value to the variable

```js
 let columns: [{
```

you have a colon instead of an equals sign, it should be:

```js
 let columns = [{
```